# keep decimal after summing up float with string

Tags: swift, string, sum

When I try to sum up 2 decimal float with 2 decimal string I get a 1 decimal in return.

```
let defaulPrice = Float(0.00) //2 decimal
let price = "100" //price in string

let floatPrice = Float(price)!/100
let tempPrice = String(format: "%.2f",floatPrice) //returning string "1.00" in 2 decimal

let finalPrice = defaultPrice + Float(tempPrice)! // 1.0 giving me back 1 decimal
```

How can I make finalPrice keep its 2 decimal?

Comment: Why do you convert `floatPrice` to a String just so you can convert it right back to a `Float` to do the addition? There's no point to that conversion.

Comment: `NumberFormatter`

Comment: First you do the calculations, then you convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up concepts of strings and floats here.

This is wrong:

> let defaulPrice = Float(0.00) //2 decimal

```
let defaulPrice = Float(0.00)
print(defaulPrice) // prints 0.0
```

you can only influence the amount of fraction digits after the separator (.) when you convert the float to string, which will be kind of printable representation.

```
Float(0.00000) == Float(0.0)
Float(0) == Float(0.0)
```

All mathematical operations should be done with numbers. Then convert the result to a string with a format (representation) you want (using the NumberFormatter from your other question) – here you can define how many fraction digits you want to display.